# Why can't we edit our profile while our account is temporarily suspended?

Tags: support, profile-page, account-suspension

As just few days ago my account was suspended for irregularities, so at that time I just tried to edit my profile to make my profile look better, but after clicking on the edit profile button, it showed

> Page not found

I tried editing my profile from another Stack Exchange site, but after editing it didn't change anything.

The blog post [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) says

> Your account will be locked at 1 reputation.
>
> Your user page will have a visual indication that you are in timed
> suspension, and for how long.
>
> You will be unable to vote, ask, answer, or comment.

However, there was no mention in the whole post that you wouldn't be able to edit your profile while suspended.

### Question

So why wasn't I able to edit my profile while I was suspended? Is there any special reason behind this to prevent anything? Or is it a bug?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's probably a feature to prevent a locked user from vandalizing his profile, adding profanities, that kind of stuff.

Imagine if a user got banned for a month for just being offensive / harassing, a "thorn in the eye".
It's really a bad idea to allow users like that to edit their profile.

Perhaps the most simple answer would be what **@[l4mpi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1110381/l4mpi)** [stated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262093/why-cant-we-edit-our-profile-while-our-account-is-temporarily-suspended#comment50696_262093):

> *"Why can't I use the site when I'm suspended?"* - Because you're suspended.

<sub>... where *"use"* basically means anything other than read access.</sub>

Comment: @l4mpi: I hope you don't mind me adding your comment to my answer ;-)

Comment: The most simple answer is actually incorrect. You can use the site for reading, getting your messages, etc.

Comment: Now you're just nitpicking.

Comment: Just to clarify my edit here, and give you some sort of credit, @FinalContest: I feel the addition I made should go without saying. Especially since the OP said he was able to read the site. However, since you insisted _"The most simple answer is actually **incorrect**."_ (Slightly inaccurate, maybe. But Incorrect? no), I added it. Now that's all I'm going to say about this any more.

Comment: Your answer is still incorrect. You can flag this critic for moderator attention again instead of thank you, but I already explained. You **do not** have access to all read functionality. Those that require reputation are not available. Anyway, I will not try to help you anymore. You apparently do not take critics, nor do you appreciate them, nor did you upvote the answer where these came from, etc. You are focusing on arguments rather than improving your post. Constructive people will not say for clarification and improvement "Guy, you are just nitpicking". That is the real NC comment.

Comment: Wow... [Pot, meet kettle](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262093/why-cant-we-edit-our-profile-while-our-account-is-temporarily-suspended/262094?noredirect=1#comment50803_262096). My point is that it really doesn't matter what ___exact___ features a suspended user can access. The reason the user can't access certain features is __because the user is suspended__. That's the point of this answer.

Comment: @Final, Need I remind you that you do not have access to my vote / flagging history? Who says that one upvote on your deleted answer doesn't come from me? (Also, no point in crediting deleted posts, eh?) Who says I flagged the comments you left here?

Comment: You are not really answering the OP's question about what features are available. You are saying you cannot use the site, which is incorrect, not true, false, wrong. You can use the site. I appreciate you do not get what features, but then why bother with answers instead of comment. I think I explained that correctly, and got no critic about that. Yet, I did not see your upvote, but anyway, let us leave it with that. It is not productive to focus on the argument rather than giving correct answers.