# Disable editing of the chat about section while suspended

Tags: feature-request, chat

In chat, there was recently a troll that used the chat-about section to bypass the ban and continue communicating. There's been a lot of weird stuff in there, including threats.

Anyways, this has happened while the user has been suspended in chat and the main site (first chat only, then the main site as well).

So, my feature request: Disable chat about section editing for the user while they are suspended in chat or on the main site. It already exists for [the main site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262093/why-cant-we-edit-our-profile-while-our-account-is-temporarily-suspended), but the chat about section doesn't seem to be affected in any way, even while suspended on the main site.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we had a similar thing a few years ago in the Tavern on the Meta and I recall a bug report similar to this one was created but I can't find it now on MSE.

Comment: @rene [Suspended users can still edit their chat profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256621/165773)?

Comment: @gnat looks about right, yes. Thanks.

Comment: How can you bypass a chat suspension using the about section?

Comment: Don't you actually have to keep looking at the user's profile to be able to see their "communication"? Or did I misunderstand? In the former case this doesn't seem very disruptive to me.

Comment: @AndrasDeak when it contains inappropriate content, insults and threats, it becomes a problem.

Comment: If you notice insults or threats in the profile, that's more than enough reason to flag the user for mods. This is not to say that the feature-request is without merit.

Comment: @gparyani I specifically didn't mention (a) specific user(s) to not blame them again years later. I would appreciate if you didn't either. All we need to know is that it did happen before so it is clear this FR is not based on a single incident.

Comment: @chade_ suspended users should not be able to send any message, in any form, to anyone. By cursing people in the chat about me, they bypass this, in a very bad way.

Comment: @gparyani please don't call out users for being suspended. It's not our place.

Comment: How do you know they used the edit of the chat profile to circumvent the chat ban? Do you have proof of this?

Comment: @YvetteColomb yes, I have a few screenshots (AFAIK, Madara does too). Though that's case-specific, and it's been handled

Comment: @Zoe ah, so a mod knows? that's good

Comment: @YvetteColomb The case I mentioned is just as an example; it was handled, but I mention it to use it as an example of when it becomes a problem, and specifically why banned users shouldn't be able to edit the chat about section.