# Do suspended accounts lose their non-default profile picture?

Tags: discussion, profile-picture, account-suspension

I was checking on questions I visited yesterday, some of which are by the same user. Yesterday, this user had a non-default profile picture, but today I observed that their reputation was reduced to 1 and their profile picture had reverted to the default image.

Clicking on their username revealed that their account is currently suspended. I am curious to know whether the account owner personally removed their profile picture or if it was automatically reset to the default image as a result of the suspension.

Is it due to the suspension? If yes, what is the rationale behind it?

Comment: If I had to guess, it was because the user switched their profile picture to an obscenity, which a mod subsequently changed after invoking the suspension.

Comment: I hazard a guess that the profile picture (which of a rude gesture) they changed to was likely the "final straw" after their actions in another (now deleted) post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, suspended accounts don't lose their non-default profile picture automatically. For instance, [this user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2801559/guest271314) is suspended until Feb 2024 but has the same profile picture they had prior to the suspension.

Most likely, the user you're referring to changed their picture to something unsuitable, so the picture was removed by a "mod" (not really mods at the moment, most of them, due to the strike, but...).

Comment: Funny (or not?) that I thought of exactly the same account to check whether or not this is the case.

Comment: Question is, can suspended users change their avatar at will? Should they be able to?

Comment: @Kaiido What were they they up to this time?

Comment: Not sure ;-) but they have an habit of arguing a lot over everything, everywhere, and IIRC they started with a small cool down period that got extended quickly.

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack - I don't think they can, the idea is that they're suspended from the platform entirely (other than viewing), see [this related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262093/) saying they can't edit their profile (which makes sense, imagine the vitriol). I suspect what happened is the user changed their picture to something inappropriate and then either that, itself, took them over the line for a suspension or they did it at the same time as / just before something that got them suspended.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder but if the suspension is "only" for one site, not network wide, the user can edit in a site where they're not suspended, then Copy to All Sites. So question is, is it smart enough to not copy to sites where the user is on a suspension?

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack - Let's hope so, but I'm fairly sure there have been bugs of that kind before, so it wouldn't surprise me if you've thought of a loophole.